# Php loop issues

Tags: php, json

This is my code

```
 $rQuery="SELECT * FROM rowManagr WHERE id=0";
    $rResult = $mysqli->query($rQuery)or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while($row = $rResult->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $rowQuery='SELECT * FROM row_vid WHERE rowid='.$row['rowid'];
        $rowResult = $mysqli->query($rowQuery)or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

        while($rowHome = $rowResult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if($rowHome['showid']!=0 )
            {

                 $json[] = array(....);


            }


                elseif($rowHome['season_id']!=0){
                   $json[] = array(....);

               }
               elseif($rowHome['showid']==0 && $rowHome['season_id']==0){
                $json[] = array(....); 


               }





    }

$jsondata[$row['rowname']]=$json;
$g['responses']= $jsondata;
    }



     $jsons = json_encode($g);
     echo $jsons;
```

output of this code is (example)

```
{"responses":{
  "Seasons":[
     {"1a"},
     {"2a"},
     {"3a"},
     {"4a"}
  ],
  "Other Show":[
     {"1a"},
     {"2a"},
     {"3a"},
     {"4a"},
     {"1b"},
     {"2b"},
     {"3b"},
     {"4b"}
  ],
  "Videos":[
     {"1a"},
     {"2a"},
     {"3a"},
     {"4a"},
     {"1b"},
     {"2b"},
     {"3b"},
     {"4b"},
     {"1a"},
     {"2a"},
     {"3a"},
     {"4a"},
     {"1c"},
     {"2c"},
     {"3c"},
     {"4c"}
  ]
```

}
}

Seasons ,Other Show, videos contains 4results but in output Seasons is copied into  Other Show and Seasons and  Other Show is copied into videos.

the actual output should be

```
{
   "responses":{
      "Seasons":[
         {"1a"},
     {"2a"},
     {"3a"},
     {"4a"}
      ],
      "Other Show":[
         {"4a"},
     {"1b"},
     {"2b"},
     {"3b"},
     {"4b"}

      ],
      "Videos":[
         {"1c"},
     {"2c"},
     {"3c"},
     {"4c"}
      ]
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please strip down your code to the relevant parts!

Comment: Can you please explain us what does it means `my problem is responses.Seasons,responses.OtherShow and responses.Videos Show consists of 4 result, but in output responses.Seasons gets copied into responses.OtherShow and responses.Seasons,responses.OtherShow is copied into responses.Video`??

Comment: check the actual output should be and output of this code...resulte are being duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look on my code.

It will gives you code as you define in your example.

**It is also an example.**

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','DBName');
    $json = '{ responses {"Seasons:["';
    $rQuery = "SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME";
    $rResult = $mysqli->query($rQuery)or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while($row = $rResult->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $json .= "{" . $row['name'] . "}" ;
    }
    $json .= "]}}";
    echo $json ;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion , the array is not empty , i have just removed it do to decrease code size.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the array `$jon` before the inner while loop:

```
while($row = $rResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rowQuery='SELECT * FROM row_vid WHERE rowid='.$row['rowid'];
    $rowResult = $mysqli->query($rowQuery)or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    // init $json
    $json = array();

    while($rowHome = $rowResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($rowHome['showid']!=0 ) {
             $json[] = array(....);
        }
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` to get out of while loop and also use `else if` structure instead of `nested if`.

Comment: Put `continue;` in `if` block of showid and seasonid and else part of seasonid.